# Populate a gallery's comboboxes based on values inside a form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a form and a gallery which contain 2 fields:-

1. The form has a field named "Artwork description", for entering values separated by commas.
2. The gallery contain fields named "Quantity for each artwork", for entering values separated by commas. this will be a number for each art work, as follow:-

[image]

so for example d1 artwork had 4 & 1 quantities

d2 has 1 & 1 quantities

d3 has 1 & 2 quantities

d4 has 9 & 2 quantities.

so in total we have 12 items scattered among different networks (network-a and network-b), types and art works.

then i have a gallery which shows the 12 items with a a combobox to fill the artwork. now i want instead if manually filling the 12 artworks, to auto fill the artworks based on the quantities i have and avoid having the same artwork on 2 successive items (times that comes directly after another item where i am ordering them by ID)

[image]

any advice on how i can accomplish this ?